How can I get into a global variable if the user is using a mobile browser using Blazor Server?
I am facing an issue with blazor server in .NET 8.
I want to get into a global variable if the user is using a mobile browser in C#.
public class AppState
{
  public bool isMobile {get;set;}
}

//In program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppState>();

And then somewhere in my JS:
window.myApp= {
isMobile: function () {
    return ($(window).width() < 768);
 }
}

//Code to run
appState.isMobile = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("myApp.isMobile");


My question:
Where can I load the JS to make the property isMobile available everywhere ?
So far I've tried, or suggest :

In the program.cs but I got an exception
In the Routes.razor file as a CascadingValue (how ?)
In the Layout page in the OnAfterRenderAsync method but then child components render first so it's useless.


You might want to avoid using Scoped services with Blazor Server. "Scoped" doesn't mean what you think it means when dealing with Razor Components.

@gunr2171 - Why?  A Scoped service exists for the duration of the SPA session, which I believe is what the OP is trying to achieve.

I would have an "Enter" button on the landing page, and call the JS in the onclick event for that button.  This is also a good time to queue up video or audio that you want to autoplay, as those require user input as well.

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to render to get the screen size before you can make some UI/UX decisions.  Along the way you also need to handle pre-rendering.
The way to achieve this is to defer rendering of the normal content until the first render event has occurred, and a JS context exists.
Anyone please comment if I've missed something critical here.
First a modified JS script to return the screen width.  I've moved the decision logic into the C# code:
wwwroot/app.js
window.myApp = {
    getScreenWidth: function () {
        return window.innerWidth;
    }
}

Registered in App.razor
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

No change to the service or registation.
Next the critical component that gets the screen width and defers primary content rendering.
@if (_preRendering)
{
    //Do whatever you want to inform the user that we are prerendering 
    <div class="alert alert-info m-5">Pre-Rendering</div>
}

// only render the content when we have the AppState data.
@if (_ModeIsSet)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
    [Inject] private AppState _appState { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; } = default!;

    private bool _ModeIsSet;
    private bool _preRendering => HttpContext is not null;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Don't do anything when pre-rendering
        if (_preRendering)
            return;

        // Yield so the component renders and we have a JS context to query
        await Task.Delay(10);
        var width = await _js.InvokeAsync<int>("myApp.getScreenWidth");
        _appState.IsMobile = width < 768;

        // Set so the normal content is rendered on the SetParametersAsync completion render 
        _ModeIsSet = true;
    }
}

Finally modify Routes.razor:
<MobileDetect>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
    </Router>
</MobileDetect>

My Demo Page:
@page "/"
@inject AppState AppState
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-primary">@this.AppState.IsMobile</div>



Thank you so much, it worked like a charm !!!

Hello, I have an issue with your solution I can't call a regular API, how could I fix it ? Thank you !

You need to create a new question.
